# How to unlock phone using ADM application?

Tags: applications

I'm using Asus Zenfone and I'm not able to unlock it. I've tried ADM but without success. Utility says that password wont be used when there is a lock pattern. How to use this application?

Answer (score 0):

here:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Android+Device+Manager+-+Bypass+Screen+Lock+on+any+Android+Device/34600

remotely unlock your phone

Answer (score 0):

Basing on Google's support site, it doesn't say that the Android Device Manager could be used to unlock a device that's already locked. [Remotely ring, lock, or erase a lost device](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160500?hl=en&ref_topic=6160499). It mainly depends on what is asked from your phone, usually, it's the PIN code, Passcode, or Pattern lock that was added on your device. If this doesn't work, I suggest Factory Device Reset.